# Using pandas to append hdf5 table leads to a pytable exception AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, hdf5, pytables

Using pandas(0.16.2)  pytables(3.2.0) hdf5(1.8.15.1) from this months Anaconda 2.3.0 distribution.

The first csv file is read correctly and written as hdf5 table. However the second file leads to an AttributeError in pytables. (see comment in code below)

```
with pd.HDFStore("%s\\myScores.h5" % outPath, mode = 'a', complib= 'zlib') as hdfStore:
    for sFile in sFileLst:
        absFileName = os.path.join(xScoresDir, sFile)
        df =  pd.read_csv(absFileName, delimiter=';', error_bad_lines=False)
        print df.head()
        hdfStore.append('/xScores', df, min_itemsize = 50)
        #problem exists at appending table nr2
        #class Table(fixed) in pytables
```

Exception:

```
    debughdf5.py,  line 88
        hdfStore.append('/xScores', df, min_itemsize = 50)
    pytables.py,  line 912, in append
        **kwargs)
    pytables.py,  line 1268, in _write_to_group
        s.write(obj=value, append=append, complib=complib, **kwargs)
    pytables.py,  line 3805, in write
        self.write_data(chunksize, dropna=dropna)
    pytables.py,  line 3812, in write_data
        nrows = self.nrows_expected
    pytables.py,  line 2956, in nrows_expected
        return np.prod([i.cvalues.shape[0] for i in self.index_axes])
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
    i.cvalues does not exist! self.index_axes = [name->index,cname->index,axis->0,pos->0,kind->integer]
```

Even with overruling the automatic type inference in the read_csv by means of  `dtype= {colName1:np.float, colName2:np.str}` the problem stays the same.

Probably this problem is introduced in the latest update, since I do not remember seeing this before.

Is there a workaround possible by improving the above code?

Thanks!

Comment: If in conda the pytables version is degraded to 3.1.1, the code starts to work again, so this problem is definitely related to pytables 3.2.0

Comment: Try to create a minimal example that reproduces the exception. This would allow others to play around with it and would increase the chance that somebody finds a solution. It would also help to file a bug report and potentially fix it.